# Abstracting try/catch PHP - stripe error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, stripe-payments, abstraction

I am handling errors from the Stripe API - everything works fine using the standard try/catch block provided in the Stripe docs:

```
try {

  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

  //card errors

  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");

} catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

However, this is a lot of code and I find myself repeating it. I'm a bit stuck on how to neaten it up. Something like this would be ideal:

```
try {

  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...

} // catch all errors in one line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a function that handles it for you:

```
function makeStripeApiCall($method, $args) {
    try {
        // call method
    } catch (...) {
        // handle error type 1
    } catch (...) {
        // handle error type 2
    } ...
}
```

Now:

1. How to pass the `$method`? There are several ways to do that; for example:

   ```
   $method = 'charge';
   $this->stripe->{$method}($args);
   ```

   ```
   $method = [$stripe, 'charge'];
   call_user_func_array($method, $args);
   ```

   ```
   $method = function () use ($stripe, $args) { return $stripe->charge($args); };
   $method();
   ```

   Choose what fits your situation best.
2. How to handle errors exactly?

   You should catch the specific Stripe exceptions and convert them to your own internal exception types as appropriate. There are a few broad types of problems you'd want to handle differently:

   1. bad requests, e.g. card declined: you want to catch those errors in the calling business logic code directly and do something based on the specific issue
   2. service down, e.g. `Stripe\Error\ApiConnection` or rate throttling: you can't do much with those except try again later, you'll want to catch those errors somewhere higher up and present the user with a "sorry, try again later" message
   3. bad configuration, e.g. `Stripe\Error\Authentication`: nothing much that can be done automatically, you can present the user with a 500 HTTP server error, ring the alarm bells and get a devop to fix the authentication keys

   These are basically the kinds of exception types you want to define internally and then catch them as appropriate. E.g.:

   ```
   ...
   catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
       trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_WARNING);
       throw new TransientError($e);
   }
   ...
   ```

After all this, you will have reduced API calls to something like this:

```
try {
    return makeStripeApiCall('charge', $args);
} catch (BadRequestError $e) {
    echo 'Card number invalid: ', $e->getMessage();
}
// don't catch other kinds of exception here,
// let a higher up caller worry about graver issues
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it's very useful. The main problem I have will be in passing the method because the try block will vary a lot. It might be making a charge, retrieving a customer, creating a subscription, changing a subscription plan, adding a coupon - all with different arguments and metadata.

Comment: An anonymous function should be the most flexible then.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into that